# Jquery addClass() using vertical-align css property

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, addclass

I have an input box, pretty much like twitter (I am using bootstrap). When pressing it, I want it to expand, which it does. The problem is the placeholder and input text start in the middle. I have tried several ways to change it without success:

1. `$(this).css({"height":"80px","vertical-align":"top"});`
2. `addClass method`

Can you help me find a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $("selector").addClass("yourclass");                                 if you have see demo please check http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_addclass

Comment: Don't use that resource. There are much better ones like the official jQuery docs.

Comment: Your question is not clear. In the middle of what? expnded where? show HTML And JSfiddle

Comment: Refere to the documentation http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Can you show the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertical-align` doesn't work with text inputs.. Try setting the padding instead. You don't need to set the height either, just use bottom padding to force the text to the top. If you want multiple lines consider using a `textarea` instead.

`$(this).css({"padding-bottom":"60px"});`

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/67097)</kbd>

Comment: I tried the padding just now. The thing is that with the padding the input box keeps expading and the text doesn't reach the top, even if I set max-height.

Comment: Previously I had the textarea. The problem was with the transition from the input box to textarea. Again, just like twitter, I want to press the single line input box and expand seamlessly to a bigger box (that might be a textarea).

Comment: Did you try my demo? What browser are you using?

Comment: Twitter is using a contenteditable `div`. That may be another solution you can try.

Comment: I tried now the demo, made the changes and it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Is the way twitter is using it better? any special impact I should take into consideration? (I am trying to create more less the same user experience)

Comment: The contenteditable DIV may work better for multiple/wrapping lines of text. Please go ahead and accept this answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Isn't it possible to wrap text using an input (type text) field? I am having problems with it..